# Linq GroupBy TakeWhile?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

Using EF4 and Linq

I have a data structure which looks like this:

```
 parentid   childid  version
        1         2        1
        1         3        1
        1         4        1
        1         2        2
        1         3        2
        1         5        2
     ...
```

That is, I want to select the parentid, childid but only for the highest version, for every parentid there is in the database.

My first attempt was this:

```
var links = data
           .GroupBy (link => link.parentid)
           .Select(ig => ig.OrderByDescending(link => link.version).First())
           .Select ( link => new ....... );
```

However, this obviously only selects one of the child id's for each parent id..

In the sample data above I want to get the child ids 2,3,5 from version 2 for parent 1 that is..

Comment: You should group by parentid and within a parentid group by version. I haven't got time to work it out now. I'll try later if still necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a subquery like this:

```
var links = data
    .OrderBy(link => link.parentid)
    .ThenBy(link => link.childid)
    .Where(o => o.version == data
            .Where(i => i.version == o.version).Max(l => l.version))
    .Select(link => new ....);
```

This way, I get all the parentid's in the db with only the children with the max version for that specific parent.

Answer (score 0):

This should meet your requirement..

```
var links = data.Where(x => x.version == data.Max(y => y.version))
                .OrderBy(x => x.childid)
                .Select(x => new {parentid = x.parentid, childid = x.childid});
```

if you need only for parent 1 then

```
 var links = data.Where(x => x.version == data.Max(y => y.version))
                 .Where(x => x.parentid == 1)
                 .OrderBy(x => x.childid)
                 .Select(x => new {parentid = x.parentid, childid = x.childid});
```

Comment: Thats not even valid code. version is a scalar field and thus can not be used in a max query..